# What's the difference between Foo::class.java and Foo::javaClass?

Tags: kotlin

To initialize my logger apparently I need:

```
val LOGGER : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo::class.java);
```

If I do:

```
val LOGGER : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo::javaClass);
```

It complains that the parameter type is not compatible with `getLogger`. However according to the API, both are `Class<Foo>`.  How are they different?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `javaClass` is an extension property that returns the *runtime Java class* of an instantiated **object**. In your case, it is being used as a property reference, which will give you a `KProperty1<Foo, Class<Foo>>` representing the extension function itself:

```
val T.javaClass: java.lang.Class<T>
```

You could use this in combination with a receiver, e.g. if `Foo` provided a default constructor you could say:

```
Foo::javaClass.get(Foo())
```

which may be simplified to:

```
Foo().javaClass
```

Using `::class.java` on the other hand, gives you the Java `Class<?>` as described in ["class references"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) directly. All three possibilities in a simple example:

```
val kProperty1: KProperty1<Foo, Class<Foo>> = Foo::javaClass
kProperty1.get(Foo()) //class de.swirtz.kotlin.misc.Foo
Foo::class.java //class de.swirtz.kotlin.misc.Foo
Foo().javaClass //class de.swirtz.kotlin.misc.Foo
```

Answer (score 7):

`javaClass` is an extension property which returns the runtime Java class of an object.

```
/**
 * Returns the runtime Java class of this object.
 */
public inline val <T: Any> T.javaClass : Class<T>
    @Suppress("UsePropertyAccessSyntax")
    get() = (this as java.lang.Object).getClass() as Class<T>
```

It can be called on an instance of a class, for example:

```
println(Foo().javaClass)    //class Foo
```

However, `Foo::javaClass` give you a [property reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#property-references) of type [`KProperty1<Foo, Class<Foo>>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/index.html) instead of a Java class instance which can be used to get the class of an instance of `Foo` through reflection:

```
val p: KProperty1<Foo, Class<Foo>> = Foo::javaClass
println(p.get(Foo()))    //p.get(Foo()) returns a Java class Foo
```

Therefore, it is wrong to pass a `KProperty` to `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` which accepts a Java class.

Answer (score 4):

[`Foo::javaClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-class.html) is a reference to a `val` defined as

```
inline val <T : Any> T.javaClass: Class<T>
```

So you'd have to call it on an instance of Foo like `foo.javaClass`.

`Foo::class` gives you the actual `KClass` of `Foo` and `java` is a property of `KClass` defined as

```
val <T> KClass<T>.java: Class<T>
```